# Is it possible to calculate with declarations only?

Tags: functions

simple Example:

maximize $u(x), x$

solution would show constraints:

$\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x} = 0$

$\frac{\partial^2 u(x)}{\partial x} < 0$

etc...

or do I always have to explicitly define functions?

Comment: Any program can be expressed as a Turing machine, without functions or variables, only states and a (potentially) infinite tape. I'm not sure if that's what you want, though.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing.  Generally it's not possible, but there is some very limited support.  `Maximize` cannot do this.

Comment: @nikie : "Turing machine" and "infinite tape" don't tell me anything im familiar with. Probably I'm not advanced enough.

Comment: @Szabolcs : Ok, that answers my question. I would need to use this funcionality with maximization. Thank you

Comment: @Jan You can differentiate manually in that case.  You can e.g. do `D[f[x] g[x], x] == 0 && D[f[x] g[x], {x, 2}] < 0`